# Twitter og tags not working?

Tags: facebook, twitter, meta-tags

I have placed these meta tags on a site I'm working on. I then have a 'share this page' type feature which content authors can override the default content which appears in the share window using the og tags which are working fine for Facebook, however Twitter is not working.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="test test test" />
<meta property="og:title" content="test title goes in here" />
```

Reading around a bit, I can see that it shows [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/cards/markup-reference)
that the fall back is the og tags which I already have. I've also read about twitter cards however I don't think I'm using them as they describe - its just a share button? This post explains using different ones:
http://davidwalsh.name/twitter-cards

I'm wondering if anyone can shed any light on why the og tags may not work? Do you need to apply for something from Twitter??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed specific tags for Twitter and Facebook after all. The doco was out dated - would recommend reviewing new doco if you need to do this as it changes all the time..